# How to search scoped package name through `npm`?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using `npm search` to search npm packages by their names. But I couldn't find a way to search the scoped packages. For example, when I search `@babel` packages I get nothing:

```
$ npm search '@babel'
No matches found for "@babel"
```

however, when I remove the `@` from the front. I get something:

```
$ npm search 'babel'
NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE       | VERSION  | KEYWORDS
Babel                     | Babel puts a soft…   | =lucaswoj       | 2011-06-30 | 0.0.1    |
babel-core                | Babel compiler core. | =hzoo…          | 2018-04-27 | 6.26.3   | 6to5 babel classes const es6 harmony let modules transpile transpiler var babel-core compiler
@babel/core               | Babel compiler core. | =danez…         | 2018-12-15 | 7.2.2    | 6to5 babel classes const es6 harmony let modules transpile transpiler var babel-core compiler
babel-runtime             | babel selfContained… | =hzoo…          | 2017-08-16 | 6.26.0   |
@babel/types              | Babel Types is a…    | =danez…         | 2018-12-15 | 7.2.2    |
@babel/parser             | A JavaScript parser  | =danez…         | 2018-12-20 | 7.2.3    | babel javascript parser tc39 ecmascript @babel/parser
@babel/generator          | Turns an AST into…   | =danez…         | 2018-12-15 | 7.2.2    |
```

It looks like npm search will match the text but doesn't respect the `@` sign. How can I make it more strict to search for the packages under scoped name?

I also tried blow commands but none of them work. They give me all package names which include `babel`. None of them respect `@` sign:

```
npm search /\^@babel
npm search '/^@babel'
npm search ^@babel
npm search \\@babel
```

Comment: I am using npm `6.4.1`. What version are you using?

Comment: Perhaps try clearing your local [npm cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache.html) by running; `npm cache clean --force`. Then run your search again; `npm search '@babel'` - this should cause the local index to rebuilt again.

Comment: I clean the catch but get the same result.  Does it work for you?